# Classes as parameters error

Tags: c++, oop, class, function, parameters

In Weapon.h, when I try and take a class 'Entity*' as a parameter, it says "Syntax error: identifier 'Entity'" when I compile. Additionally when I roll over the text 'target', Visual C++ Express 2010 gives me the text " *target". The Entity class is fine and I'm pretty sure it's included correctly.

(I won't post Player.h as it's unnecessary - see Library.h - but it has a header guard and includes Entity.h)

Library.h:

```
#ifndef _LIBRARY_
#define _LIBRARY_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>

//file includes
#include "Globals.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Exception.h"
#include "Weapon.h"
#include "Armour.h"
#include "Consumable.h"

//prototypes that require "Library.h"
bool Poglathon(std::vector<std::string>& text,Player *player);
bool PoglathonTown(std::vector<std::string>& text,Player *player);

std::map<std::string,Weapon*> init_weapons(void);
std::map<std::string,Armour*> init_armour(void);
std::map<std::string,Consumable*> init_consumables(void);

#endif //__LIBRARY__
```

Weapon.h:

```
#ifndef _WEAPON_H_
#define _WEAPON_H_

#include "Shopable.h"

class Weapon : public Shopable{
private:
    int Damage;
public:
    Weapon(int c,int d,std::string n) : Shopable(c,n),Damage(d){}
    std::string getDesc() const{
        return getName()+"\t"+tostring(Damage)+"\t"+tostring(Cost);
    }
    int getDamage() const{return Damage;}
    int DamageTarget(Entity* target){
        int DamageDealt = 0;
        //do damage algorithm things here
        return DamageDealt;
    }
};

#endif
```

Shopable.h:

```
#ifndef _SHOPABLE_H_
#define _SHOPABLE_H_

#include "Library.h"

class Shopable{
protected:
    std::string Name;
    int Cost;
    std::string Description;
public:
    Shopable(int c, std::string n):Cost(c),Name(n){}
    std::string getName() const{return Name;}
    int getCost() const {return Cost;}
    virtual std::string getDesc() const = 0;
};

#endif
```

Entity.h:

```
#ifndef _ENTITY_
#define _ENTITY_

#include "Library.h"
#include "Weapon.h"
#include "Armour.h"
#include "Consumable.h"

class Entity{
public:
    void printStats() const;
    void heal(double health);
    std::string name;
protected:
    //player stats
    double str;     //strength
    double wis;     //wisdom
    double ref;     //reflex
    double hp;      //health points
    double maxHp;   //maximum health points
    double i;       //initiative
    double inte;    //intelligence
    double c;       //courage
    int gold;       //gold
    int xp;         //experience
    int ap;         //armour points
    int wd;         //weapon damage
    int lvl;        //level
    int sp;         //skill points
    Weapon* weapon;//weapon
    Armour* cArmour;//current armour
};

#endif
```

Comment: Not a solution, but a comment: you might want to try and move unnecessary includes away from the headers and into the implementation files, replacing them with forward declarations: for example, there's really no need for `Entity.h` to include `Weapon.h` or `Armour.h` when it could just forward declare the classes. Perhaps that kind of modification would make the root of this problem easier to find, too.

Comment: what @Heandel said. And culling the includes would make it plainer.

Comment: Forward declare the classes? And @Heandel, I posted all the code that I thought might be the cause of the problem. I just posted the lot instead of shortening it, sorry.

Comment: @Pig Head -- When you ask for assistance, please include a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (sscce.org)](http://sscce.org/). Had your example been short and self-contained, you might very well have found the problem yourself.

Comment: @Rob The problem was making it self contained and correct.

Comment: Yes, @Pig Head, that is a problem. But it is a problem that you are better equipped to solve than we are. Start by deleting a few lines at a time, which lines you suspect are unrelated. Delete functions that aren't called, class members that don't illustrate the problem. And, at each step, recompile your program to see if the error is still present. Eventually, either 1) you've discovered precisely which deleted line caused the problem, or 2) you've create a sample so short as to make it obvious which line causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your headers include each other because your classes refer to each other.  (But your compiler doesn't suffer from a stackoverflow because of your include guards - that's a good thing!)

You should arrange your header files hierarchically, ie there are files at the 'top' which #include nothing and files 'below' which include some of the top ones and so-on down the hierarchy.  But at no point should there be 'loops'.

In order to break your loops in your code, any classes that refer to each other should forward declare any mutual dependencies and only refer to dependency names and not their members.

e.g.

Entity.h

```
class Weapon;
class Entity{
    ...
    Weapon* weapon;
};
```

Weapon.h

```
class Entity;
class Weapon{
    ...
    int DamageTarget(Entity* target);
};
```

Notice how Weapon.h only refers to `Entity*`.

You will need to define `int Weapon::DamageTarget(Entity* target)` in Weapon.cpp

Comment: How can I avoid a loop if there's a file which includes everything and everything needs to include? (Library.h)

Comment: @PigHead: There's always a way.  In the case of Library.h I would guess that you can delete most lines.  The only includes it needs are vector and string.  The rest can be forward declared.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, classes must be declared *before* they are referenced.  You are `#include`-ing Weapon.h in Entity.h, but at that point, the compiler doesn't know about the existence of `class Entity`.

You will either need to change the order in which things are declared, or add a *forward declaration* "above" `class Weapon`.  It can simply be:

```
class Entity;
```

That tells the compiler that there is such a name as `Entity`.  However, it doesn't tell it *anything* about what members it has, so you can't actually do anything with it, other than declare variables of `Entity *` and `Entity &`, and pass them around.

Comment: How can I change the order in which things are declared? Can you explain that in more detail please?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <entity.h>
```

Or forward-declare only in the header

```
class Entity;
```

This makes compilation a bit faster (you still need to include it to use in the implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Weapon.h doesn't #include Entity.h, or anything that recursively includes it. Therefore, it doesn't know about the class `Entity`.

Comment: Weapon.h includes Shopable.h which includes Library.h which includes Player.h which includes Entity.h.