# typedef across same namespace in different header files

Tags: c++, namespaces, typedef

I'm currently learning c++ and struggling with some code:

Garden.h:

```
#ifndef GARDEN_H_
#define GARDEN_H_

#include <vector>
#include <boost/tr1/memory.hpp>

#include "Shape.h"
#include "Utils.h"

namespace cma {
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<cma::Shape> ShapePtr;
    typedef std::vector<cma::ShapePtr> GardenPlan;
}

#endif /* GARDEN_H_ */
```

Utils.h:

```
#ifndef UTILS_H_
#define UTILS_H_

#include "Garden.h"

namespace cma {
    void printList(GardenPlan const & p, std::ostream & o);
}

#endif /* UTILS_H_ */
```

The compiler output:

```
In file included from ../src/Garden.h,
                 from ../src/Utils.cpp:
../src/Utils.h: error: variable or field 'printList' declared void
../src/Utils.h: error: 'GardenPlan' was not declared in this scope
../src/Utils.h: error: expected primary-expression before '&' token
../src/Utils.h: error: 'o' was not declared in this scope
```

I seriously just don't get it.

Comment: Note the typo in your Garden.h header guard.

Comment: You can remove the `#include "Utils.h"` from Garden.h as you don't need it and this causes some problems

Comment: The typo wasn't the source of the failure. And I don't want to remove `Utils.h` as I would like to only `#include "Garden.h"` in my main program. Is there a way around?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classes as parameters error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857009/classes-as-parameters-error)

Comment: @cimnine - yes, there is: remove `#include "Utils.h"`, create a new header, that includes `Utils.h` and `Garden.h` and then include the new header in your main program. Problem solved (:

Comment: @cimnine: If I thought the typo was the source of the failure, I'd write it as an answer and not a comment. It's still an error, though, so I thought it would be helpful to point it out ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a cyclical include problem.

You're including `Garden.h` in `Utils.h` and `Utils.h` in `Garden.h`.

You either need to put both definitions in the same header file or forward declare one of the types.

However, you don't actually need to include `Utils.h` in `Garden.h` so removing that include should solve your problem.